# When change default language angular-translate does not update key translate in service

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

When i use **angular-translate**. By changing the default language in another language, the following code does not work

```
$translate('HEADLINE').then(function (headline) {
         $scope.headline = headline;
}, function (translationId) {
         $scope.headline = translationId;
 });
```

But the code below works very well:

```
<ANY>{{'TRANSLATION_ID' | translate}}</ANY>
```

Someone knows how can I write the translated code I want to translate into the controller?

Comment: You can use $translate.instant('HEADLINE')

Comment: $scope.headline =  $translate.instant('HEADLINE') , 
 $scope.headline  when  $translate is switch does not update ...

Comment: Okey now i understand your problem. $translate don't observe anything. It will just translate your "HEADLINE" to the current language. You need to use the filter or the directive inside the HTML or listen to the  "$translateChangeSuccess" event and fire your translation function again

Comment: thank you, it's very useful. I think in Angular 5 this issue has been fixed?

Comment: AngularJS != Angular. angular-translate is only for AngularJS 1.x.x.
Also this isn't something that need to be fixed it works correct.

Comment: yes!ً **@ngx-translate/core** library written for Angular. 
It is completely different I said maybe this scenario is there too.